# How to download only the latest images from Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have the following problem and do not quite know how to solve it:
I am loading pictures from one device to Firebase Storage Cloud. With another device, I want to download them from Firebase Storage.

So far my implementation looks like this. Every time I open the app it re-downloads and displays all the images. I can't effectively get it to save the images in the app (NOT GALLERY) and just check if there is a new image that hasn't been downloaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for, is to cache images on an Android device. This means that once you download it, you will not need to download it again, it will always be read from the cache.

For Android, there are a few libraries that do that. One would be [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), and another one would be [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/). If you're using however Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, then you can use [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/).

Comment: Hey Filler. Did you try one of the solutions above? Did any of them solve your caching problem?